# aligning the search bar beside the nav menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the search bar beside the nav menu. I used `float:right;` to shift it to the right side but regardless of using padding and or margin the search bar seems to end up on the lower line than the nav menu. What am I seem to be missing here?

below is my code:

```css
.nav-bar {
  max-height: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 200px;
  width: 80%;
}

.box-nav-bar ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.box-nav-bar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  outline: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.box-nav-bar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: block;
}

.box-nav-bar ul li:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.box-nav-bar ul .sub-menu ul li {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 150px;
}

.box-nav-bar ul .sub-menu {
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}

.box-nav-bar li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu li {
  width: 100% !Important;
}

.sub-menu li:hover .sub-sub-menu {
  display: block !important;
}

.sub-sub-menu {
  display: none !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

.box-nav-bar li:hover .sub-menu li:hover {
  display: block;
}

.sub-sub-menu li {
  width: 100% !important;
  display: block !important;
  padding: 20px !important;
}

.search-form {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <nav class="box-nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="/Home">HOME</a></li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">SERVICES</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Dolor sit amet  </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Conse ctetur </a>
            <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Latest</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Archive</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">PROJECTS</a></li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">CONTACTS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <form class="search-form" action="search.php" method="GET" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <label class="search-form_label">
                <input class="search-form_input" type="text" name="s" autocomplete="off" placeholder=""/>
                <span class="search-form_liveout"></span>
              </label>
    <button class="search-form_submit fa-search" type="submit">search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `display:inline-block;` to **.box-nav-bar** to prevent it from taking the the whole width of the parent

> Note that this will only work in larger screen

```css
.nav-bar {
  max-height: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 200px;
  width: 80%;
}

.box-nav-bar ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.box-nav-bar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  outline: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.box-nav-bar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: block;
}

.box-nav-bar ul li:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.box-nav-bar ul .sub-menu ul li {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 150px;
}

.box-nav-bar ul .sub-menu {
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}

.box-nav-bar li:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu li {
  width: 100% !Important;
}

.sub-menu li:hover .sub-sub-menu {
  display: block !important;
}

.sub-sub-menu {
  display: none !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

.box-nav-bar li:hover .sub-menu li:hover {
  display: block;
}

.sub-sub-menu li {
  width: 100% !important;
  display: block !important;
  padding: 20px !important;
}

.search-form {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

.box-nav-bar {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <nav class="box-nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="/Home">HOME</a></li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">SERVICES</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Dolor sit amet  </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Conse ctetur </a>
            <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Latest</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Archive</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">PROJECTS</a></li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">CONTACTS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <form class="search-form" action="search.php" method="GET" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <label class="search-form_label">
                <input class="search-form_input" type="text" name="s" autocomplete="off" placeholder=""/>
                <span class="search-form_liveout"></span>
              </label>
    <button class="search-form_submit fa-search" type="submit">search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `<form>` inside the `<nav>`

```
<nav class="box-nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="/Home">HOME</a></li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">SERVICES</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Dolor sit amet  </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Conse ctetur </a>
            <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Latest</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Archive</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">PROJECTS</a></li>
      <li> <a href="/Home">CONTACTS</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form class="search-form" action="search.php" method="GET" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <label class="search-form_label">
                <input class="search-form_input" type="text" name="s" autocomplete="off" placeholder=""/>
                <span class="search-form_liveout"></span>
              </label>
    <button class="search-form_submit fa-search" type="submit">search</button>
  </form>
  </nav>
```